# Size of clicked images in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

*(Not sure whether to call this a bug or not; feel free to change it to discussion or feature-request.)*

When clicking on images in the Android app, instead of zooming in to fill the screen, the image is displayed even smaller than its original size. (The image in the screenshot is 512 pixels wide, the image popup window is 680 pixels wide, but the image is displayed at 354 pixels.)

I'm aware that setting sizes on mobile screens isn't straightforward, but isn't it logical to fill the whole image popup window? Or does the app only zoom at 1x, 2x, 4x... or something like that?

[image: Android app screenshot]